# Group by column and add columns to count for occurences of values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from random import randrange

groups = [randrange(1,8) for x in range(50)]
df = pd.DataFrame(groups,columns = ["group"])
df["dummy1"] = pd.Series(np.random.randint(20,size = len(df)))
df["dummy2"] = pd.Series(np.random.randint(20,size = len(df)))
```

Grouping the data is obvious, let's say like this:

```
groups = df.groupby("group").agg({"dummy1":[np.sum,np.mean]})
```

However i want to count the occurences of specific values in `df["dummy1"]` for example. And in the groups i want to have a column that shows the count for each value. For example like this:

I want to have something like this:

```
      dummy1            count_1 count_3
         sum       mean                
group                                  
1        128   9.846154       2       1
2         70  10.000000       4       3
3         89  12.714286       2       3
4         65   8.125000       4       4
5         93  15.500000       4       3
6         69  11.500000       3       1
7         31  10.333333       4       2
```

Is there any easy way to do this? I tried a solution of just adding new columns that show if the `df["dummy1"]` value is for example 1 and then use a sum on the column while aggregating the groups. However, this is insanely slow for even my dataset with around 100k entries.

Comment: does `count_1` for the sum of `128` have a value of `2` because there are two values of that data in your dataset? whats wrong with `df.groupby('group')['dummy1'].size()` ?

Comment: For that group, the value of 1 occures 2 times. So yeah, that is what it means.

Comment: `df.groupby('group')['dummy1'].size()` computes the size of each group, this is not what i want. I want to count the occurence of spefic values for `df['dummy1']` within the group, which is different from the size of the group

Answer (score 2):

You can try `value_counts` with `groupby` and then join with your `groupby().agg()`:

```
groups = df.groupby("group")

(groups.agg({"dummy1":[np.sum,np.mean]})
   .join(groups['dummy1'].value_counts().to_frame('count').unstack())
)
```

Comment: This looks like a decent approach. Can i specify what values i want to look for, since this gives a new column for all values?

Comment: I don't see a clear way to select the values. You might be better off with two separate `groupby`'s.